# Solve The Partial Differencial Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the DE : $t\frac{\partial ^2 U}{\partial x \partial t}+2\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=x^2$

Here's the solution:

(step 1) $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[t\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}+2U]=x^2$ , then integrate with respect to x

(step 2) $t\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}+2U=\frac{1}{3}x^3+R(t)$ , then multiply with t

(step 3) $t^2\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}+2tU=\frac{1}{3}tx^3+tR(t)$

(step 4) $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}[t^2U] = \frac{1}{3}tx^3+t R(t)$ , then integrate with respect to t and we obtain

(step 5) $t^2U=\frac{1}{6}t^2x^3 + G(t)$

(step 6) $U=\frac{1}{6}x^3+F(t)$

However I don't understand why we need to multiply it with $t$ after step 2? Can't we integrate it directly with respect to $t$?

And also, why in step 4 the $2tU$ is gone?

Comment: It's an Integrating Factor. When you multiply by t from step to, the terms on the left are a derivative of what is in [] in the next line. That's why  $2tU$ disappears.

Comment: i'm sorry but can you explain more? i still don't get it

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically integrate either side in step 2, but it doesn't lead anywhere:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \left(t\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} + 2U\right)\mathrm{d}t
&=\int t\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t + 2\int U\mathrm{d}t\\
&= t U - \int U\mathrm{d}t + 2\int U\mathrm{d}t\\
&= t U + \int U\mathrm{d}t
\end{aligned}
$$
where I integrated by parts to obtain the second line. As you can see, this introduces an anti-derivative of $U$ which makes the problem more difficult.

Multiplying by $t$ allows you to use the product rule in the opposite way you normally do. Indeed, if I have two functions $f, g$ then $f^\prime g + fg^\prime$ can be simply written as $(fg)^\prime$ by the product rule. Multiplying by $t$ allows you to do this with $f=U$ and $g = t^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much, i understand it now.

Comment: Do you know about why the $2tU$ is dissapear?

Comment: The product rule. $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (t^2 U) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (t^2) U + t^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (U) = 2t U + t^2\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}   $$

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I just realized it now. Thank you so much!